# Crashing with loop of xmlhttp requests

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to rewrite this macro from ie.application to http requests in VBA.
The macro navigates to a URL, GETs the html then parses and scrapes the required data.

It works well with one request, but when I try to do this with a FOR loop with thousands of URLs Excel crashes.

I think I should "close" the connection in some way before going to the next loop, but I did not find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
Sub GetQuotes()
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument


    For r = 1 To 10

'*****GO TO PRODUCT PAGE*****
        path= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value
        myurl = "https://some_domain.com" + path

        xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
        xmlhttp.send
        html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText



'*****GET PRICE*****
        If Not html.getElementById("some_id") Is Nothing Then
            price = html.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value = price
        Else
            price = "empty"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value = price
        End If

        Next r

    End Sub
```

*XML and HTML references are active*

Comment: Add `DoEvents` before `Next r`. Now check?

Comment: Find out where the tipping point for crash is and either process in batches (that are under this point) or try adding waits at a certain step (like every 500 or something else)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squeeze in a

```
Do While xmlhttp.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

after the send. Your current code will fire all requests almost at once. With this, you will wait for the page to load before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

A do-while with DoEvents inside just after the request is sent.

A DoEvents alone just before the next r.

Using one of them only, did not work.

Comment: Are you sure you got the result using `A do-while with DoEvents` even when you have sent a request using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` @user10523399? So far my knowledge goes: making use of that very loop (when you are not using IE) is totally useless.

Comment: Like I said it did not work only by that by I had also to add a doEvents before the next statement.